# How can I use a PHP email variable with cron?

Tags: php, email, cron

I have a service that sends out text to an email entered after x number of days. I want to use cron, but I know that because my PHP script uses variables, this would not work. How can I change my PHP or do anything that would allow me to use cron (or even something else)? I just need something where it will store the emails then send them. I'm **really** new to PHP, so keep it simple please.

Here’s my code:

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        $headers = "From: Memory Jet <your_company@example.com>\r\n";
        $to_visitor = $_POST["email"];
        $common_data = $_POST["message"];
        mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $common_data, $headers);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Being new to PHP, have you used a database at all yet?  Being familiar with persisting data to a database will make this a lot easier, as then your site could just queue an email message in the database and then your cron-executed PHP script could check the database for email messages to send and send them.  This would effectively de-couple the web application from the scheduled application, which is a good thing.

Comment: could you maybe provide some code or docs? I have not used databases yet

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php is a good place to start.  I'm assuming you'll want to use MySQL as your database, and there's no shortage of tutorials online.  Be aware, however, that a _lot_ of database code you find online has glaring security vulnerabilities.  It's something you'll want to continue to learn and improve, not just get it working and run with it.  As a beginner, pay specific attention to topics such as "SQL injection attacks."  They're pretty easy to prevent if you know what to look for.

Comment: Thank you, but would I be able to also use the method that safka said?

Comment: Sure, provided that whatever is calling the script (which I thought was an automated `cron` job) knows what the email address is.  If this ends up requiring that you queue the cron jobs dynamically for each email to send, I wouldn't recommend it.  But I don't know your setup, so that might not be the case.  In any event, being able to persist data across applications in a database is worth learning.

Comment: I see, thanks for all your help. I'm off to try it all out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use argv array to read CLI params - http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

if your script is named `/bin/script.php` then if invoked as `/bin/script.php xyz` the following:

```
$email = $argv[1];
```

will assign `'xyz'` to `$email`.

just read doc I've provided - there's all you need

Comment: is there a way that I could automatically add the arguments? Through a script or something?

Answer (score 1):

if you're wanting to store the data to transmit later, either using a database to store the info or writing it to a file would allow you to retrieve it.

If you need to potentially edit and manipulate the data later on, I'd recommend using a database.

I'd also recommend looking at http://www.tizag.com/phpT/ for some good, simple tutorials for PHP that really helped me when I first got going.